# Changing file names based on their filetype extension

Tags: cmd, terminal

So am kind of new to using command lines in Terminal and stuff. However,  I was interested if someone could help me with this thing. I would prefer if somebody with Terminal knowledge can help, but Command Prompt is good as well.

I have a folder with name say `Videos` and inside this folder I have multiple files: one mp4, one ppt, one pdf, and one doc. The video name is say "Movieking1-1" and all other file types have name as "sample". 
Now what I would like is a set of commands which searches for all the extensions like *.pdf and *.docs in the folder and give it the name of that as the one for the .mp4 and add -yt So if my folder was like this:

```
Movieking1-1.mp4
sample.docx
sample.pdf
```

The command should work and change the name for the file in that folder as

```
Movieking1-1.mp4
Movieking1-1-transcript.docx
Movieking1-1-transcript.pdf
```

There are no other docs or pdfs either in the same folder. 
I am asking help because i have to do this for more than 100 folders.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advances

Comment: Can you share with us the code that you have tried? Questions without code usually go to https://superuser.com/

Comment: @lit unfortunately i dont have any code yet since i didn't know where to start from. Am fairly new to cmd and terminal. I'll post the thread on the website you suggested! :)

Comment: see `for /?` for a start. Try `for /r %%a in (*.mp4) do echo %%a, %%~na`. This should give you a good basis. (batch file syntax; for use directly on command line, use `%a` instead of `%%a`)

Comment: This is what I tried so far but it doesn't seem to work `\for file in */*.docx; do mv $file $(dirname $file)/$(dirname $file)transcript.docx`@lit @Stephan

Comment: That's Linux syntax. I'm out...

Comment: @ArnoldHernk - The `cmd` tag is for Microsoft Windows cmd.exe users. Which OS are you using?